# Cannot install torch 1.7.0 in apple M1

Tags: python, macos, pytorch, apple-m1, yolov5

I'm trying to install yolov5 on my Mac M1 using the followwing commands:

```
 git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5.git
```

then:

```
cd yolov5
```

But when I tried to install the requirmets from the requirments.txt file with below command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The instllation complete but show below error at the end:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.7.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.7.0
```

I don't know which version of torch I have to use to complete the installation

Comment: Try installing manually and remove torch from requirements.txt `pip install torch==1.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this issue has been a regular for the latest python versions.

Could you please try downgrading your python version to 3.8 and retry your requirements.txt

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/47354